# Configure a qbo3 Workflow to pause for 18 hours

Tags: qbo3

I have two tasks in a qbo3 Workflow that need to be performed at least 18 hours apart, but only during business hours (8am to 5pm):

- Task A
- (pause for 18 hours)
- Task B

Can Step 2 above be configured to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Polling Step` to do this. Polling steps run on a schedule, and evaluate data conditions until the condition is true.  To meet your requirement:

- Create a `Schedule` designed to run every hour between 8am and 5pm
- Create a `Polling Step` to see if 18 hours have passed

#### Creating the Schedule

From `Configuration > Schedules`, create a new schedule:

- Schedule: `Every Business Hour`
- Description: `Daily repeating 1 hour between 8am and 5pm`

[image: Daily repeating 1 hour between 8am and 5pm]

#### Create the Polling Step

From `Templates > Workflows`, select your workflow and choose `Add a Polling Step`:

- Step: `Wait 18 hours`
- With: `Summary Data`
- Logic: `format:dateDiff(//*[DecisionStep="Wait 18 hours"]/CreatedDate, "now", "h") >= 18`
- Polling: `Every Business Hour`

The key to this functionality is the `format:dateDiff()` function, which is calculates the hours between the `CreatedDate` of the `Wait 18 hours` step and `now`.

If we've passed the 18 hour mark, the `Wait 18 hours` will be marked complete, and any steps dependent on the `Wait 18 hours` step will be started.

If we've not yet passed the 18 hour mark, the `Every Business Hour` schedule will queue the step to be evaluated again in an hour.  If this hour happens to be after business hours, the schedule will advance the next run date to the following morning @ 8am.

[image]