# Ensure qbo3 tasks occur at different times of the day

Tags: workflow, qbo3

We have a `Customer Outreach` task that prompts an agent to call a customer. Should the customer be unreachable, we want to ensure that up to 2 subsequent calls for the same customer occur at least a day apart, and are made at a different time of the day. After 3 attempts, we're done.

How can one configure a qbo3 task to enforce this?

Answer (score 0):

The key to implementing this requirement is leveraging a `Workflow`, in particular `If/Then` and `Polling` steps that do a bit of date calculation.

A `Workflow` can be used to manage this situation, with the following steps:

- Step 1: First Customer Outreach (Task = Customer Outreach)
- Step 2: First call before noon?
- Step 3: First Wait 22 hours (Depends on Step 2 == false)
- Step 4: First Wait 26 hours (Depends on Step 2 == true)
- Step 5: Second Customer Outreach (Task = Customer Outreach)

  - Depends on Step 3 or Step 4
- Step 6: Second call before noon?
- Step 7: Second Wait 22 hours (Depends on Step 6 == false)
- Step 8: Second Wait 26 hours (Depends on Step 6 == true)
- Step 9: Second Customer Outreach (Task = Customer Outreach)

The same `Customer Outreach` task can be reused for steps 1, 5, and 9.

Steps 2 and 6 are `If/Then` steps, that use the following expression:

```
format:formatDate(//*[DecisionStep="First Customer Outreach"]/ActualCompletion, "hh") >= 12
```

where:

- `format:formatDate()` parses a date, in this case returning only the hour (`hh`)
- `//*[DecisionStep="First Customer Outreach"]/ActualCompletion` is the completion date of the first step

Steps 3, 4, 7 and 8 are `Polling` steps configured with and expression similar to:

```
format:dateDiff(//*[DecisionStep="Wait 18 hours"]/CreatedDate, "now", "hh") >= 22
```

For more detail on Polling steps that pause a workflow, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65136927/configure-a-qbo3-workflow-to-pause-for-18-hours/65136928#65136928).